# Using an EV SSL certificate for your site with non-EV SSL content

Tags: nginx, ssl, lighttpd, ssl-certificate

If I purchase an EV SSL certificate for a site that is using static content from a non-EV SSL site does that effect the EV SSL certificate presentation on the main www site?  For example:

www.example.com (uses an EV SSL certificate)
static.example.com (uses a standard SSL certificate)

Will users on www.example.com still see the green bar with the company name if the CSS and images are being served from static.example.com?

Answer (score 3):

The insecure content blocking functionality is implemented by each browser and not really standardized.  However, I do not know of any browser that is doing this.

Browsers display the green bar when the certificate presented has an EV policy OID, which are looked up in a list the browser ships with.  I don't know of any browser that implements exceptions to this rule for remote includes from https:// locations without EV, though this isn't to say that in the future nobody will think this is a good idea and implement it.

Comment: Opera was at one point at least downgrading EV sites that included non-EV content, but IDK if theyre still doing that or not.

Comment: It's certainly safer to get EV certificates for all your things, for this reason.